# Shader link error after installing latest NVidia Quadro driver (311.35)

Tags: opengl, gpu

I just installed the latest NVidia driver for Quadro 4000 cards.From this moment any of my shaders linking fails with shader link error.
It is worth noting I am using OpenGL 4.2 with separate shader objects.My OS is Windows7 64bit .
Before the update I had 309.x version of the driver and everything worked fine.
Now I rolled back to the version 295.x and it works again.
Anyone knows something about it?Can it be a driver bug? If yes, what can be done about it?

Here is a simple pass through vertex shader that fails:

```
#version 420 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvs;
layout(location = 2) in vec3 normal;


smooth out vec2 uvsOut;
void main()
{
    uvsOut=uvs;
    gl_Position = position;
}
```

Another question ,is it possible that NVIdia tightened shader version semantics rules? I mean ,I am using OpenGL compatibility profile but in GLSL mark #version 420 core.Can it be the problem?

**Update:**

Some more info from Program Info Log:

**error C7592: ARB_separate_shader_objects requrires built-in block gl_PerVertex to be redeclared before accesing its members.**

Yeah , also the driver writer has typos "accesing "  ;)

Now , I actually solved the linking error by adding this :

```
out gl_PerVertex
{
    vec4 gl_Position;
};
```

It is strange that previous drivers didn't enforce redefinition of gl_PerVertex block.Now ,while this addon solved the issue with the linking, it opened another one where some varying uniforms don't work.For example I have in vertex shader:

```
  out vec4 diffuseOut;
```

And in fragment shader:

```
 in vec4 diffuseOut;
```

Then

```
  OUTPUT = diffuseOut;/// returns black while red is expected.
```

**Update 2 :**
Ok , now it becomes clear - the new drivers are stricter on shaders input/output variables.With the older driver I could define several "outs" in a vertex shader but without defining also their "in" match in the fragment shader.It worked.Now it seems I am forced to have the exact match between declared "ins" and "outs" in vert and frag program.Strange that no errors are being thrown but the result is that the defined "ins" become empty in the destination.

Comment: Is this question about your code and bugs there, or are you more worried about the driver? I know the difference is vague, but the current phrasing seems driver-focused, which is probably better suited for SuperUser. If you're more concerned about problems with your code that *might be caused by* the drivers, I would consider rephrasing the question toward that end.

Comment: Well ,I guess it is both because if it's something related to how the new driver expects OpenGL to be used then it is code bug ,otherwise it is driver but I can't figure it out that is why I am here...Do you suggest to post it on SuperUser?

Comment: Have you tried running the code on ATi or Mesa? Both tend to be stricter and more correct than nVidia, with Mesa (by some reports) being the closest to a reference implementation you're likely to find and ATi preferring to error-out rather than allow invalid code. Running on additional platforms/hardware, or digging up any analysis tools that exist (something like RenderMonkey) may point out some issues.

Comment: As far as I know Mesa supports GL 3.2 at most. ATi has no sense for me as my project target GPU is NVidia exclusively.But even if I wanted I have only NVIdia cards around ...

Comment: What's the info log after the link error?  (See `glGetProgramInfoLog`.)

Comment: "*any of my shaders linking fails with shader link error*" What linker error?

Comment: @MichaelIV: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if the specification requires this, or are you asking what you need to do to fix it?

Comment: I am asking for both.See my second update please.